# Which version of oracle instant client should I download for my linux

Tags: oracle

My linux info:

`Linux cubietruck-plus 3.4.39 #7 SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 1 09:34:33 CST 2016 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux`

Which instant client should I download here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the listed ones:

Your arch is ARM based, and oracle doesn't provide ARM binaries.

There is a long shot, of using qemu to emultate x86 and run the client, but I've never tired it.

Comment: I agree with it. Oracle instant client doesn't provide the ARM version.